# Почему не axios получает токен только после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Когда прохожу авторизацию jwt токен записывается в localstorage. Но в запросах токен не летит, после перезагрузки страницы всё нормально

Хук useAuth для авторизации:

```js
    import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
    const storageName = 'test'

    export const useAuth = () => {
      const [token, setToken] = useState(null)
      const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)
      const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null)

      const login = useCallback((jwtToken, id) => {
        setToken(jwtToken)
        setUserId(id)

        window.localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify({
          userId: id, token: jwtToken
        }))
      }, [])


      const logout = useCallback(() => {
        setToken(null)
        setUserId(null)
        window.localStorage.removeItem(storageName)

      }, [])

      useEffect(() => {
        const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(storageName))

        if (data && data.token) {
          login(data.token, data.userId)
        }
        setReady(true)
      }, [login])


      return { login, logout, token, userId: userId, ready }
    }
```

```js
    import axios from 'axios'
    const development = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

    const getToken = () => {
      let token = null
      const localStorage = window.localStorage.getItem('test')
      if (localStorage) token = JSON.parse(localStorage).token
      return token
    }

    export default axios.create({
      baseURL: development ? 'http://localhost:5005' : 'https://test.com',
      headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}` }
    })
```

Функция подтверждение авторизации:

```js
      const onSubmitAuth = useCallback(async values => {
        await axios.post(`/api/auth`, values)
          .then(res => {
            login(res.data.token, res.data.id)
            history.push('/hero/city')
          })
          .catch(err => {
            setError(err)
          })
      }, [])
```

Comment: Наверное, стоит спросить это у того кто вместо axios получает токен. А если серьезно - по этому кусочку невозможно назвать причину. Наверное, она в порядке выполнения операций записи и чтения в LS.

Comment: @yar85 Я добавил весь путь авторизации

Comment: `axios.create` выполняется только один раз, при инициализации скрипта, поэтому заголовок устанавливается только при загрузке страницы. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону axios interceptors

Comment: Омг... `axios.create` выполняется **не** при загрузке страницы! Этот метод выполняется в момент его вызова, и никак иначе. Вызов вовсе не всегда происходит при загрузке страницы. ТС может вызывать этот метод после получения токена, но это будет неудобно (придется экспортировать функцию-фабрику, и заводить флаг инициализации). Что более удобно - в `login` добавить выражение вида `axios.defaults.headers.authorization = \`Bearer ${getToken()}\`;`, тем самым обновив дефолтную настройку импортированного инстанса (ранее созданного через `create` выражением экспорта).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import axios from 'axios'
const development = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const getToken = () => {
  let token = null
  const localStorage = window.localStorage.getItem('test')
  if (localStorage) token = JSON.parse(localStorage).token
  return token
}

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: development ? 'http://localhost:5005' : 'https://test.com'
})

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${getToken()}`
  return config
})

export default instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто обновлять значение заголовка в дефолтных настройках экземпляра axios (созданного при экспорте модуля).

Либо в `login`, если не смущает импорт экземпляра axios в том же модуле:

```
const login = useCallback((jwtToken, id) => {
  setToken(jwtToken)
  setUserId(id)

  window.localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify({
    userId: id, token: jwtToken
  }))
  axios.defaults.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${jwtToken}`
}, [])
```

, либо в `onSubmitAuth` (здесь это более логично, по-моему):

```
const onSubmitAuth = useCallback(async values => {
  await axios.post(`/api/auth`, values)
    .then(res => {
      login(res.data.token, res.data.id)
      axios.defaults.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`
      history.push('/hero/city')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      setError(err)
    })
}, [])
```

Разница с вариантом принятого ответа - в том, что эти два варианта не потребуют никакого усложнения перехватчиком запросов (который вызывается при **каждом** запросе, и при **каждом** запросе он будут через функцию `getToken` дергать `localStorage`, бесполезно перечитывая и репарся одно и то же значение).
Мы добавляем токен в общую конфигурацию при его получении, и все.

Comment: что произойдет, если токен был обновлен в одной вкладке браузера, а запрос отправляется в другой?

Comment: @NikitaUmnov, то же самое, что и при одной вкладке. Тут задействован `localStorage`, токен читается из него - поэтому, зависимость скорее от **порядка операций чтения и записи в сторейж** (от логики **общего алгоритма** работы приложения), а не от вкладок. Это говорилось еще до ответов, в первом комментарии... что именно неясно в данном утверждении?

Comment: в вашем варианте он в него только записывается, а не читается. Если вкладка 1 обновит токен, запишет его в LS и заголовки, что будет во вкладке 2? Как заставить ее обновить токен в заголовке?

Comment: @NikitaUmnov, ответ и не предполагает готовое решение (которое можно скопипастить, и самостоятельно ничего не делать) - это именно ответ, а не выполнение заказа. Да, ответ показывает конкретно запись токена в настройки, потому что предполагает выполнение чтения тем же методом который указан в вопросе. Относительно того допроса который ты сейчас мне тут устраиваешь, о том как работает _твой_ код: ранее я **дважды** написал о важности _порядка операций чтения и записи_, как наиболее вероятной причины проблемы... Какие именно действия ты предпринял в отношении этого дважды сделанного уточнения?

Comment: @NikitaUmnov, `getToken` надо вызывать при первичной инициализации вебприложения, чтобы новые вкладки открытые _после_ получения токена сразу читали его (это у тебя вроде уже сделано, разве нет?). Если же ты хочешь **перечитать** токен во всех вкладках (включая открытые ранее) при его записи в LS на одной из вкладок - то используй подписку на DOM-событие `'storage'` глобального объекта `window`: вызывая `getToken` в слушателе данного события. Но все то что касается разных вкладок, вообще за рамками данного вопроса, и об этом лучше было бы создать отдельный вопрос.